# File Upload Issue in Safari 5.0 using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to upload a file in `AngularJS` for safari browser as `FileReader` API is not supported in Safari 5.1.

I am using the below code to upload it using AJAX. Can you please confirm whether I am doing it right.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', $files[i]);
http.post(url, fd, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
})
.success(function(data){
    alert("success"+data);
})
.error(function(){
    alert("failure");
});
```

Is there a possibility of timestamp also being returned for the file upload should it be passed as a parameter.

Comment: you can put the meta in GET, and use POST to ex: `xhr.send(inpFile.files[0])`

Comment: How to pass parameters with the file in XHR ?